How to setup color composition between different layers in leafletjs?
I'm combining several tile layers using leaflet JS and I'm struggling to understand what kind of color composition is used there, is there a way to influence color mixing behavior?

For example diagonal line on the picture above comes from the tile source as 4e4e4e color gray line, but after mixing it's not longer gray, and if color picked it shows as a86728 line. How can I make it to stay gray?
Layer is added as
window.L.tileLayer
    .wms('--redacted--', {
      layers: 'zones:eez',
      format: 'image/png',
      transparent: true,
      className: 'EEZLayer',
      STYLES: 'zones:eez-lines-only'
    })
    .addTo(map);


